# How could I measure RF transmission power from SMA connector without having a RF wattmeter equipment?

Tags: rf, multimeter, testing, power-measurement

I need to measure the RF power of a radio transreceiver, and since I haven't specific RF wattmeter equipment, 
I'm wondering how I could do this using a classic multimeter.

I would avoid to disassemble the radio equipment so I want to do this check at SMA connector (if viable).

Comment: At what frequency?  How much power?  Do you have anything else, like a scope?  Have you check the FCC test report for the product?

Comment: @ChrisStratton I have also an oscilloscope. Power in 0-10W range (how much is what I suppose to discover measuring It). For the frequency matter consider e.g. 400 Mhz

Comment: That's a bit more challenging given the frequency.  At those power levels you must not operate it without a proper load resistor, which needs to be seriously non-inductive at that frequency.   If you had such, one thing you could start by doing would be measuring the increase in power consumption when transmitting.  What **exactly** is this gear?  Make, model, regulatory registration (FCC or otherwise) identifier, specs...

Comment: @ChrisStratton the equipment is a Baofeng GT-3TP MKIII supposed to be 8W VHF 136-174MHz / UHF 400-520MHz Chipset: RDA5802N FM Radio Receiver \ RDA1846S Transceiver \ TDA2822L Audio Amplifier

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: you can't.

If you want to measure power at radio frequency, you'll need a device designed to do so. Your multimeter is specifically designed to suppress RF, as it's pure noise to the things it's designed to measure.

What you'd need to do is build a converter from the RF signal to some slow signal that your multimeter could measure. But building (and calibrating) that is actually the *hard* part of building an RF wattmeter.

So, no, you can't.